# Как можно автоматизировать изменение настроек Lotus Notes клиента?

Tags: lotus-notes

Есть компьютеры с запущенными Lotus Notes 8.5 клиентами. Необходимо зайти в меню параметры и выбрать определенную настройку включением одного чекбокса. Как это можно автоматизировать? Вариантом было бы иметь программу, пользователь запускает ее, чекбокс выбирается. Также можно было бы поправить файл с настройками автоматизированно, но точно не известно где этот файл и что в нем править. Там несколько файлов .nsf  меняется, структура не известна.
Возможно autoit помог бы поставить чекбокс. Не знаком с этим средством.
В каком направлении искать решение?